# next js state change doesnt change value of input

Tags: reactjs, input, next.js

I have this piece of code but that does not change value of input field when state changes.State changes when user clicks on a row. State is changing as i printed the value outside text field but that does not reflect in input field. I tried with value instead of defaultValue but it doesnt work.

```
                           <Controller
                            name="name"
                            control={control}
                            defaultValue={selectedRow.name}
                            value={selectedRow.name}
                            rules={{
                              required: true,
                            }}
                            render={({ field }) => (
                              <TextField
                                variant="outlined"
                                fullWidth
                                id="name"
                                label="Name"
                                error={Boolean(errors.name)}
                                helperText={
                                  errors.name ? 'Name is required' : ''
                                }
                                {...field}
                              ></TextField>
                            )}
                          ></Controller>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you use react-hook-from (https://react-hook-form.com/).

`value` and `onChange` should be inside of `TextField` like this.

```
<Controller
  name="name"
  control={control}
  rules={{
    required: true,
  }}
  render={({ field, value, onChange }) => (
    <TextField
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
      variant="outlined"
      fullWidth
      id="name"
      label="Name"
      error={Boolean(errors.name)}
      helperText={
        errors.name ? 'Name is required' : ''
      }
      {...field}>
    </TextField>
  )}
/>
```

Comment: thanks for your help..yes i am using react hook form. I treied yor solution but that didnt work for me. The value is not changing when state changes.

Comment: My input needs to be readonly and its value will be from state. const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState({
    _id:"",
    name:"",
    image:"",
    slug:"",})

Comment: If it's readonly, I think you don't have to use `react-hook-from`. This is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-field-jikfp.

Comment: Thanks. The issue is resolved for read only. I have another react-hook-form thats not read only. How will i resolve this issue in that form?

Comment: Could you please show me your code?

Comment: <Button onClick={() =>handleOpebEdit(row)} size="small" variant="contained">
              Edit
</Button>

Comment: const handleOpebEdit = (row) => {

  setSelectedRow(row)
  setEditOpen(true);

};

Comment: const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState({
   
    _id:"",
    name:"",
  });

Comment: <Dialog open={openEdit} onClose={handleClose}>
<DialogContent>
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(updateSubmitHandler)} className={classes.form}>
<List><ListItem>
<Controller
name="tag"
control={control}
defaultValue={selectedRow.name} render={({ field }) => (
<TextField
variant="outlined"  fullWidth id="tag" label="tag"
 {...field}
  ></TextField>
  )}></Controller>
  </ListItem></List><Button onClick={handleCloseEdit}>Cancel</Button>
<Button variant="contained" type="submit" fullWidth color="primary">Update</Button></form></DialogContent><DialogActions></DialogActions></Dialog>

Comment: the row passed to handleOpenEdit(row) is in this format { _id:"53464747755663",
    name:"fish",
  }